# Flutter project takes an absurd amount of time to run

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

flutter takes an awful lot amount of time to run(between 5-20 minutes,sometimes it even crushes) and it happens every single time i try to run a flutter project.
i tried to look how to fix it and removed gradle and built again but it didnt work,here's the log after i ran flutter run-v,would really appreciate if someone could help https://www.mediafire.com/file/evg0ko7z9395ltm/flutterlog.txt/file

Comment: Does it also take a lot of time to run `flutter build apk`?

Comment: yes it absolutely is